# Context Menu on Slack Message

Tags: slack, slack-api

Is it possible to add to the Context Menu currently available to messages posted in a slack channel, preferably with a dialogue?

[image: Slack Message Context Menu]
[image: Default Options under More context menu]

**UPDATE** As of May 22, 2018, you can add to the Context Menu per the [Slack Developer blog](https://medium.com/slack-developer-blog/introducing-actions-a-simple-shortcut-attached-to-every-slack-message-e2404414ece).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Its currently not possible to customize / add to the context menu for messages in Slack.